# Initialize() method doesn't work in micro application in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

I want to do some actions before executing a controller method. But I can't because the initialize() method doesn't work in a micro application. I can check the way in Base controller and do some actions, but I think it is not valid.

Comment: Please, show us how are you trying to use the initialize method? In other words: give us the code!

Answer (score 3):

You can't overwrite the `__construct()` method of `Phalcon\Mvc\Controller` because the `__construct()` is defined as `final` and therefor can't be altered.

A workaround is to let your `baseController` extend like this (instead of `Phalcon\Mvc\Controller`):

```
class BaseController extends \Phalcon\DI\Injectable {
    public function __construct() {
        // ...
    }
}

class YourController extends BaseController {
    // do stuff
}
```

Or instead of the above shenanigans, you could use the build-in method `onConstruct`

```
class BaseController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {
    public function onConstruct() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that the `onConstruct()` method triggers when the controller is created. This is different to the behaviour of the `initialize()` method, which triggers **after** `beforeExecuteRoute()`.

Comment: I extend Controller, not \Phalcon\DI\Injectable. And I find solution - I use onConstruct in BaseController and parent::onConstruct in controller that extends BaseController, but thanks.

Comment: @АлександрКовальчук, yes you should definitely use `onConstruct`. I think my eye caught onto Juri his answer, so I thought you were trying to use `__onConstruct()`. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes because controllers in micro are only handlers. Use `__construct` maybe ?

Comment: how to use it? when I try to use it it gives me error : Cannot override final method Phalcon\Mvc\Controller::__construct()

Comment: Sure, you can't since constructor is declared as final. The best approach is to use `before` event, in $app->before() method.

Comment: Then use before i guess or use onConstruct in controller(this one should work).